# C++ issue with ifstream() taking filename from string variable

Tags: c++, string, ifstream

I am having this simple yet annoying issue.

ifstream dataFile(fileName) works fine if fileName is hard-coded or assign via a string variable however when supplied from an argument, it is unable to find the file.

I have the following code -

```
//This function will get filenames from a .txt file
//Then call getDataFromFile() with filename as argument

void getFileNames(string dataFileName){

   string line;
   ifstream dataFile(dataFileName);
   if(!dataFile){
      cout << "Error! No such file found! Ending Program." << 
      endl;
      exit(0);
    }

    while(getline(dataFile,line)){
       if(!line.empty()){
           getDataFromFile(line);
       }
    }
} 

//**Issue is inside this function**

void getDataFromFile(string fileName){

   //Files are under "data/" path -
   //To access Jan.csv - "data/Jan.csv"

   string filePath = "data/Jan.csv"; //Works
   string filePath = "data/"+fileName; //Not working - Unable to find file   

   ifstream dataFile(filePath);
 //...Rest of code
}
```

Below is the content of .txt file

Jan.csv

Feb.csv

I have tried to pass the string as c string using

> ifstream dataFile(filePath.c_str());

and still unable to find the file.

Comment: If you inspect fileName at runtime, does it contain the correct name (without invalid characters)?

Comment: Very likely there are trailing newlines.

Comment: Are the line endings in the .txt file correct for your platform?

Comment: Thanks guys. The filename is ending with "\r". Found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
Filename is ending with "\r".

For c++ newbies like me who are using codeblock -

You can check filename during run-time by setting breakpoints and check from the Debugger console.

1) Set breakpoints by clicking at the left side of the line that you want to check
[image]

2) Run the debugger by clicking the debug button at the top "the red color one".

3) Check via the debugger console
[image]

[image]

Comment: And do you know where that `'\r'` came from? (Windows \r\n newlines.) And do you know how to solve that `'\r'` being stuck to the end of the string? (Opening the *text* file in *text* mode on Windows.)